# How can WIX based installers do COM registration for both 32 and 64 bit Windows OSes?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I have a long lived installer which is using RegistryValue to setup a .Net COM server. The installer is 32 bit. I would like to have the registry settings also set for 64 bit OSes. My research shows that I need to have a separate 64 bit installer for this purpose. Fine how can I then have a bootstrapper which detects the OS and invokes the correct 32 or 64 bit .msi?

Comment: I've also seen a technique mentioned where both 32 and 64bit versions of the dll dependency are bundled within the consuming assembly. Before the assembly does a PInvoke it looks to see if the library is present. If not it extracts the appropriate bundled dll. 

This seems crazy but for my purposes would work perfectly. For future releases I may try this route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to write the bootstrapper yourself.

WiX doesn't support mixed 32/64-bit packages because Windows Installer doesn't support them. However, some commercial tools use a custom bootstrapper and 2 MSI files to handle a mixed installer.

Comment: I did not want to accept this answer but I looked into Burn in Wix 3.6 but it appears to not allow the UI of your embedded MSIs. For my purposes at this moment that does not work. So sadly I will indeed have to create my own Bootstrapper. Do look into Burn to see if it is right for you.

Comment: WiX does support 32/64 bit packages: http://jpassing.com/2009/10/09/mixing-32-and-64-bit-components-in-a-single-msi/ Check @Thomas Schlaefer reply.

Answer (score 10):

I had the same problem with a custom Windows Shell Overlay Extension that must provide a 32-bit Dll for 32-bit Windows and a 64-bit Dll for 64-bit Windows. My 32-bit msi file would only write the registry entries to the WoW6432 node on the 64-bit system, so the shell extension didn't work.

The solution (tested with wix-3.5.2519.0 on Win7 x86 and x64):

1. Create two components, one will install only on a 32-bit System and the other one will only install on a 64-bit System.
2. Use a 'Condition' element inside each Component to check for the bitness of the operating system. I used Msix64, it might also work with VersionNT64...
3. The 64-bit Component must have the Win64 Attribute set to "yes".
4. Unfortunately this will not work successfully out of the box because light.exe throws an error (error LGHT0204 : ICE80: This package contains 64 bit component but the Template Summary Property does not contain Intel64 or x64.):
5. The solution is to run light.exe with the ICE80 check disabled (use parameter -sice:ICE80). Now the msi file will be generated and can be used on both platforms.

Example:

```
<Component Id="shellext_32.dll" DiskId="1" Guid="YOUR-GUID1">
    <!-- this will be installed only on a 32-bit System-->
    <Condition><![CDATA[NOT Msix64]]></Condition> 
    <!-- copy 32-bit Dll file...-->
    <File Id="blah blah... />

    <RegistryKey Id="MyShellIconOverlay" Root="HKLM"Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\MyIconOverlay" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="{GUID...}" />
    </RegistryKey>
</Component>

<Component Id="shellext_64.dll" DiskId="1" Guid="YOUR-GUID2" Win64="yes">
    <!-- this will be installed only on a 64-bit System-->
    <Condition><![CDATA[Msix64]]></Condition> 
    <!-- copy 64-bit Dll file...-->
    <File Id="blah blah... />

    <!-- the following Registry Key will NOT be created inside the WoW6432 
    <RegistryKey Id="MyShellIconOverlay64" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\ShellIconOverlayIdentifiers\MyIconOverlay64" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
        <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="{GUID...}" />
    </RegistryKey>
</Component>
```

References:

- http://jpassing.com/2009/10/09/mixing-32-and-64-bit-components-in-a-single-msi/
- http://installing.blogspot.com/2006/04/msi-validation-in-wix.html

Comment: Thanks! I got as far as ICE80 but hadn't realized it would work if suppressed :-)