# Wix: How to write to 32bit registers on 64 bit machine

Tags: wix

I was looking for solution for some time but without success. I must admitt that I am begginer with wix. I have got one project (WPF + caliburn, using Visual Studio 2015) beeing compiled separately for x86 and x64. I use x64 machine to create both MSIs. Unfortunately during installation the setup always writes to 64bit registers which causes problems for the application.

I have created following components, trying to fix it using Win64="no" entry, unfortunately with no success. Can somone please advice correct component configuration?

```
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
  <?if $(var.Platform)="x64"?> 
          <Component Id="Registry_DefaultStoragePath" Guid="123-456-789" Win64="yes">
              <RegistryKey Root="HKLM"
                                       Key="Software\KeyName" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
                  <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="DefaultStorageLocation" Value="[DEFAULTSTORAGE]" KeyPath="yes"/>
              </RegistryKey>
          </Component>

          <Component Id="Registry_InstallType" Guid="123-456-789" Win64="yes">
              <RegistryKey Root="HKLM"
                                       Key="Software\KeyName" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall" >
                  <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="InstallType" Value="[INSTALLTYPE]" KeyPath="yes"/>
              </RegistryKey>
          </Component>
  <?endif?>
  <?if $(var.Platform)="x86"?> 
          <Component Id="Registry_DefaultStoragePath" Guid="132-456-789" Win64="no">
              <RegistryKey Root="HKLM"
                                       Key="Software\KeyName" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
                  <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="DefaultStorageLocation" Value="[DEFAULTSTORAGE]" KeyPath="yes"/>
              </RegistryKey>
          </Component>

          <Component Id="Registry_InstallType" Guid="123-456-789" Win64="no">
              <RegistryKey Root="HKLM"
                                       Key="Software\KeyName" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall" >
                  <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="InstallType" Value="[INSTALLTYPE]" KeyPath="yes"/>
              </RegistryKey>
          </Component>
  <?endif?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that `<?if $(var.Platform)="x64"?>` is handled by the preprocessor, so it is evaluated at compile-time, not runtime.

In order to handle x86/x64 runtime you can do this:

```
<component ....>
  <condition>NOT VersionNT64</condition>
  <!-- 32 bit component -->
  <!-- Add component content here -->
</component>
<component ....>
  <condition>VersionNT64</condition>
  <!-- 64 bit component -->
  <!-- Add component content here -->
</component>
```

Comment: Thank you fior the answer, that might have moved me one step further, however now i get "...but the template summary property does not contain Intel64 or X64"

Comment: Fine, here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6191591/how-can-wix-based-installers-do-com-registration-for-both-32-and-64-bit-windows) i found i nend to disable Light. Now i need to figure out how to do that under visual studio wix project....

Comment: You should use VersionNT64 - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372497(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: VersionNT64 truly helped but i needed to add     <SuppressValidation>True</SuppressValidation> tag to csproj, because light wasn't happy that there are 2 components for different architecture in my list of components (in Product.wxs)